# insertXY() to new sketch - Openlayers

Tags: javascript, android, openlayers

I am running OpenLayers.js?mobile on an Android phone.

I want to be able to draw lines & polygons from the GPS as well as clicking on the screen to add features.  If I click on the screen to begin a sketch with a new vertex, then I can call insertXY(lat,lon) or click to add vertices, and it works as expected.

However, in attempting to begin a new sketch by calling insertXY(lat,lon) on an activated OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature, nothing happens until I call finishSketch() which throws this error - "TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of null".

How can I start a sketch with insertXY()?

This should work as it does on this sample: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/editing-methods.html#

Here is the relevant javascript:

```
var map;
var draw;


map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    layers: [
        var roads = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector()
    ],
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
    zoom: 1
});



draw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(roads, OpenLayers.Handler.Path);
map.addControl(draw);

draw.activate()


function add_GPS_Line_vertex(lon,lat) {
    /* this function only works if sketch has been manually started */
    var lat = parseFloat(lat);
    var lon = parseFloat(lon);
    var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon, lat);
    lon = point.x;
    lat = point.y;
    draw.insertXY(lon,lat);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced this bug in the linked example as well (http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/editing-methods.html#) if the **mouse never hovers over the map**, and you only add points via coordinates and then call the draw.finishSkech() method.

I did this workaround by only starting the drawing when the mouse is on the map:

```
map.events.register('mousemove', map, function (e) {

   //make sure it only runs once (with a flag or something)
   if (mouseFlag == true) {
     mouseFlag = false;

     // do your drawing
     draw.insertXY(lon,lat);

     draw.finishSketch();
  }
});
```

Or if you just need to draw a shape you can always use:

```
draw.drawFeature(geometry);
```

Comment: Strange.. does look like a bug.  On android, I wouldn't expect the 'mousemove' event to be called, but then again... I'll give it a try.

Comment: I did get it to work by calling: `map.events.triggerEvent("mousedown", {xy: center_px})` just prior to: `draw.insertXY(lon,lat)`